# How to display the fetched data from API to ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, xml, postman

I am new to React and API request calls.

I have created a basic React App. I have a requirement to display the data by calling an API.
I am able to retrieve the data in the console, but finding difficult to display it on the browser.
Here is the data which I need to display :
[Console Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lun2a.png)

Here is the code that I have written (generated from Postman):

```js
import React from "react";
class FetchRandom extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append(
      "Authorization",
      "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik1yNS1BVWliZkJpaTdOZDFqQmViYXhib1hXMCIsImtpZCI6Ik1yNS1BVWliZkJpaTdOZDFqQmViYXhib1hXMCJ9.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.ge789TPniLEXtK_2zuMqZzOgLM6z1arpC5CEDAGB9J3VoEllwKCEXtlL-jzCo45aLD6VOanIbWUugdFuGXeBgeuCSV9PYRGSX9qmf5sWWvGqGM3InLq6-xHtUUE56cq9EQI634jfytq8XhUO3uLXj9x3J5rumY4WH1E0LEivCCy2A02iGmxFHsa6uTC1Iy1K_wJ4jIqlf3KRU8h0rO6HSmx2uPDeVM7KtMRFanWMgYrGUzBIk5Yh-kFCfdXFftPA_VQQGBP4A_I_3LVlbwWkvoiUmNBQYDf55Oh6onp0aDDRxViCCHcclICGGjUhh1j6fnQMmJZwOpVv7GEOKnpB1g"
    );
    myHeaders.append("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");

    var requestOptions = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: myHeaders,
      redirect: "follow",
    };

    fetch(
      "https://cooponline.sharepoint.com/sites/TestDemoFeb/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestPost')/GetItembyID(4)",
      requestOptions
    )
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));

    return <div></div>;
  }
}
export default FetchRandom;
```

Could anyone please help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the concept of **states** to achieve this in an easy way.
just create a stete like this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
```

// ///////////////////////////////////////

// in your fetch you can write something like this:

```
fech("your URL")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
setData(data);
})
.catch(error => {
setData("An Error Happened: ", error);
})
```

// /////////////////////////////////////////

then in your returned component, use it by adding curly braces and your state - here is data for example - and you're done!
also you can use some better and elegant thing like conditioanl rendering and so on for better showing.

Comment: What should I add in the return component? can you please help me with it?

Comment: <div><p>my expected data: </p>{data}</div> // or something like this...